# Google Chrome - Redirect a specific text to a link in the address bar

Tags: macos, google-chrome, script

As a reddit user, I often like to jump into a subreddit and learn something new. However, the amount of subreddits I subscribe to would make it very silly to add all of them to bookmarks on Google Chrome (Version 42.0.2311.90 64-bit). I'd like to have a script that runs each time I search for a page, and if the first three characters are `/r/`, then it redirects me to the appropriate subreddit.

Example: 
    I search `/r/funny` and Chrome corrects it to `http://www.reddit.com/r/funny`

I want to know if this is possible, and if so, how would I implement this?

I'm using a MacBook Pro running OSX 10.10.3

Comment: Did you tried bookmarks u can jump with them with only a click

Comment: Are you using RES? Might be easier to just use their shortcut manager.

Comment: What is RES? And I explicitly said that I wouldn't be using bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with a space rather than the slashes then you can add a search engine named `r` and map it to `http://www.reddit.com/r/%s`. Next, typing `r fun` will get you directed to `http://www.reddit.com/r/fun`:

- Right-click somewhere in the URL bar to click "Edit Search Engines".
- Scroll down all the way to add something like `subreddit`, with keyword `r` and URL `http://www.reddit.com/r/%s`

  [image]

That's it! Typing `r` in the URL bar, followed by a space will get you "Search subreddit", after which you can type any of its names:

[image]

Only if for some reason you also want to show it in the list of "Default search settings" on top:

- Find the search engine you just added in the long list of "Other search engines", and click "Make default" while hovering it. This will move it to the top and make it the default, so typing `fun` (without the `r` keyword) will already get you to `http://www.reddit.com/r/fun`:

  [image]
- Repeat the last step for the search engine you really want to be the default (the one that is used when you type some text in the URL bar without a keyword); your new search engine will still be in the top list and typing `r fun` will still get you redirected:

  [image]

Comment: I did all the steps, and now searching 'r funny' seems still to be searching using google. When I have google set to default. I.E. The issue seems to be with activation of using the custom search engine.

Comment: Weird, @mehmenmike, I certainly tested... You're searching in the URL bar, right? I get "Search subreddit" (see edited answer) as soon as I type the `r` and the space. What if you make it the default for just a test, and then type `funny` in the URL bar (without the `r` keyword)? Or what if you use some of the other search engines, like in my example above: type `youtube.com` followed by a space, followed by `funny`?

Comment: Still no luck, @mehmenmike?

Comment: Sorry! Completely forgot about this thing! Will have a go tonight.